# Extend the sequences of numbers and names

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

Find the next entry in each of this pair of related sequences:

> 1, 4, 6, 8, 9, ?
>
> Bobby, Joe, Johnny, Carl, Ted, ?

Note: There's no way to solve this without making use of both sequences - it's unsolvable with only the numbers.

Hint:

> The next entries in the sequences after the ones I'm looking for are **26** and **Wade** respectively.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that no worldly knowledge is needed, such as familiarity with actual persons with those names?

Comment: @humn That is not safe to assume.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1, 4, 6, 8, 9, ?
>
> > ... **14**, **26**, **27**, **34**, **45**
> >    =  
> >  [uniform numbers retired by baseball’s Boston Red Sox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Red_Sox#Retired_numbers)

> Bobby, Joe, Johnny, Carl, Ted, ?
>
> > ... **Jim**, **Wade**, **Carlton**, **David**, **Pedro**
> >    =  
> >  [first names of the players](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Red_Sox#Retired_numbers)

The hint made it clear.   You see, ever since...

> ...[Babe Ruth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babe_Ruth)
>  pitched for Boston
>  (who didn’t bother to retire his uniform #),
>  I’ve been a fan of Boston’s lefty batters.
>   
>  The “Wade” (Boggs) hint
>  rang a bell for “Ted” (Williams)
>  and “Carl”
>  (Yastremski, who was on the team with two others here
>   when I once got to a game at
>   [Fenway Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenway_Park)).
>   
>  Here’s the list:
>  
>  
>  **Bobby**   [Doerr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobby_Doerr),
>              uniform #**1**
>  
>  
>  **Joe**     [Cronin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Cronin),
>              uniform #**4**
>  
>  
>  **Johnny**  [Pesky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Pesky),
>              uniform #**6**
>  
>  
>  **Carl**    [Yastremski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Yastremski),
>              uniform #**8**
>  
>  
>  **Ted**     [Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Williams),
>              uniform #**9**
>  
>  
>   **Jim**    [Rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Rice),
>              uniform #**14**
>  
>  
>  **Wade**    (from hint)
>              [Boggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wade_Boggs),
>              uniform #**26**
>  
>  
>  **Carlton** [Fisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlton_Fisk),
>              uniform #**27**
>  
>  
>  **David**   [Ortiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Ortiz),
>              uniform #**34**
>  
>  
>  **Pedro**   [Martinez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedro_Martinez),
>              uniform #**45**

Comment: Uh, oh, baseball.`:)` (After the first partial answer was out, I hoped that the numbers would be non-primes and the names those of prime ministers of some country or other ...)

Comment: Like minds..., @MOehm, before the hint I looked up prime ministers too! (And those who _weren't_ elected PM.)

Comment: nice, i got wade boggs but know nothing about baseball and couldn't link the other numbers to players

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer.

> The next term of the first sequence is **10**.
> Why? Because the first sequence is the sequence of non-prime integers (OEIS [A018252](https://oeis.org/A018252)), and this is how we get the first 5 terms:$$1\space\space\color{red}2\space\space\color{red}3\space\space4\space\space\color{red}5\space\space6\space\space\color{red}7\space\space8\space\space9$$The terms in red are excluded. The sequence is (0-indexed)$$\alpha_n=f(n+1,0)\\f(x,y)=((x=0\rightarrow y)\land(x>0\rightarrow f(x-((\Omega(y)\ne1\rightarrow1)\land(\Omega(y)=1\rightarrow0)),y+1)))\\\Omega(x)=\text{Count of prime factors of }x\text{ including duplicates}$$Since $10$ is the next non-prime integer, it's the next term of the sequence.

Comment: It could just as well be 12: non-prime numbers of the form \$2^a 3^b\$

Comment: @PeterTaylor Can you post that as an answer please?

Answer (score 0):

The next number in the list can be

> 22

Based on [this list](https://oeis.org/A161600)

Answer (score -1):

---

These can be non-prime numbers:

---

https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2c%204%2c%206%2c%208%2c%209%2c

---